# url -autocomplete wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, autocomplete

in my current wpf project Using C#
i made a method that loads a page , so when you choose it will extract content out of source code,
a specific `div` or a specific `table` as you wish,  when you first need to select from a listbox if you would like to load a local file to extract, or you would like to load a page from the interet.

then i came to an idea that would help the user if chosen via internet to have autocomplete , as i learnd how to implement it in asp.net WebForms
it's not so complecated as i could use ajax to target the asp:TextBox. but  nead to be able to make it done via Wpf .

**1)** is there a list-source of url that i could bind my application to as datasource ?

**2)** just thought about it while searching for that url lists : 
 how could i implemnt autocomplete, is it possibole to use same approach as with 
asp.net using ajax or some other easy implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AutoCompleteBox from [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535):

```
<Page x:Class="WPFApplication.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit">

    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autocompleteCtrl"
        Populating="autocompleteCtrl_Populating" />
</Page>
```

1. You can take any kind of data sources by specify predefined list to ItemSource:

   ```
   autocompleteCtrl.ItemsSource = new List<string>{"asd","abs","vfr"};
   ```
2. Or dynamically build autocomplete list on `Populating` event handling:

   ```
   private void autocompleteCtrl_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
   {
       string text = autocompleteCtrl.Text;

       //build list
       var list = new List<string>();
       autocompleteCtrl.ItemsSource = candidates;
       autocompleteCtrl.PopulateComplete();
   }
   ```

Comment: @pochepstov. thanks it looks great, i am about to give it a test when i will find the right time (still busy with other projects so no time to play) though , what i found hard to google (to my surpise was the part of UrlData source(google has that firefox and chrom copete on the subject who does the service better) i will not rest till i will find the answer ( forgot to mention that every isp in the world has within the history of it's servers atleast good deal of urls from its users usage) still i can't get hold of it